# Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.4.0-64-generic freezes after login screen

Tags: nvidia, freeze, nvidia-optimus

I switched off the computer cutting the power supply (first mistake). When I reboot Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-64-generic, after the login screen everything freezes.

I spend a couple of hours searching and testing. It looks it is a problem with the Nvidia driver, so I should choose this driver for the system to recover. I have tried all the options in Advance Options in Grub (failsafe graphic mode, repair packages..., even console with sudo apt-get install nvidia-current. Nothing of these things have worked for me.

Finally I have decided to use an old kernel at booting. Right now I am using kernel 4.4.0-42-generic. I am not using Nvidia driver, I am using X.ORG.X.Server driver.

Questions:

1. What can I do in order to use again the kernel 4.4.0-64-Generic?
2. If I go on using 4.4.0-42-generic, should I update? I will not end reaching 4.4.0-64-generic kernel and reproducing the problem?

As requested in the comments:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h       (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 705] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `lspci`, as I have a hunch this is an optimus laptop

Comment: Which desktop are you using?

Comment: So, finally, it is fixed. Release for 16.04 4.4.0-75.96 of the LTS. Working 100% for me. You only need to update to the latest version and use it. Thanks to the hard work of the bugs chasers https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666421

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this issue by using an older kernel, which isn't crashing. I'm sure it is a bug and will eventually be fixed in the future.

Edit:
Looks like it was reported already and worked on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666421

I also experience the problems since the 4.4.0-63 release and with rtl8192cu
This has nothing to do with nvidia, since i can confirm a case where no nvidia card is present and no nvidia driver was installed.

Comment: You are right @L.S. That is what I am doing right now, using an old kernel. It looks the bug process is still going on.

Comment: So, finally, it is fixed. Released 4.4.0-75.96 of the LTS. Working 100% for me. You only need to update to the latest version and use it. Thanks to the hard work of the bugs chasers  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666421

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and it seems related to the wifi.
When I Remove the Wifi Stick the OS starts into the Desktop. As soon as i plug in the WiFi, the system freezes completely.

When booting with the stick plugged in, the system boots up until it reaches the GUI. As soon as the GUI starts, the OS freezes.

Is there a Bug report?

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour (with USB Wifi stick).
Hangs with:
linux-image-generic  (4.4.0.64.68)
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04    (4.8.0.39.10)

nvidia-361 (367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Comment: You were completely right @Axel. It is the wifi device (I get my Wi-Fi on my Desktop via a Belkin N-300 Micro Wireless USB Device). If I start with Wireless on, the system freezes. If I take away the pen, no problem. Even more, once ths system is running, if I insert the pen, the system freezes again. Should I fill in a bug?

Comment: My desktop behaves exactly the same way. Kernel 4.4.0-59 works fine for me.

Comment: According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666421

4.4.0-69 worked
4.4.0-70 broken again in Xenial

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .
press Ctrl + Alt + f1
then Login

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken upgrade
sudo apt-get --fix-missing upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

if still didn't work try: `sudo apt-get --fix-broken dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get --fix-broken dist-upgrade`
when you're finished don't forget to do `sudo apt-get update`

==================================================================================
I hope it helped.